# What is the best way to extract data from wiki tables, and links from that table to JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, wikipedia

I'm kind of new at web dev and had a question of getting data from wikipedia. I am making a personal web app that will keep track of past UFC events. I couldn't find an open source api with event details and results. However the following table on wikipedia has a lot of the info I need: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UFC_events
And I have seen several tutorials on how to get the info from a wiki table and format it into .csv format using google spreadsheets, or other software such as openrefine. But, I also want the information from each event's wikipage(fight results, winners, award winners, poster images etc.), and each event's own wiki page is lined on the table I mentioned above. I was wondering, what is the easiest way to go about extracting this information?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nokogiri gem to scrap the web page